# How to limit the user answer?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm creating a series of questions and I need to limit the user input to only "A,B,C,D" and if the user enters something else, show a warning. I'm thinking of creating an `if`  conditional to show the question, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the way I created the question:

```
     question= "Where Adolf Hitler was born?"
                + "\nA) USA"
                + "\nB) Austria"
                + "\nC) Germany"
                + "\nD) Spain";
     
     answer= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
     
     if(answer=="D") {
         points++;
     }
```

Comment: `res3=="D"` is not how to compare Strings in Java.

Comment: another way to solve that to make the answer as radio button so user select only one answer 
no need to do anything else

Answer (score 3):

I think people forget just how configurable something like `JOptionPane` can be.

Start by looking at [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

[image: Pick on]

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String message = "Where Adolf Hitler was born?";
        String[] options = new String[] {
            "USA", "Austria", "Germany", "Spain"
        };
        int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Pick one", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, 0);
        if (selectedOption == 1) {
            System.out.println("Right");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat That's interesting, because the code and image are generated in unison - the `selectedOption` is based on the index in the `options`, curious why the display order is different

Comment: @ScaryWombat The buttons are displayed in reverse order from the array, but the index is always returned correctly, select `Spain` and you'll get `3` :D

Comment: Oh, sure, I saw "Australia" :P

Answer (score 1):

It would be appropriate to use a `switch` statement like so:

```
switch (answer) {
  case "A":
  case "B":
  case "C":
    System.out.println("Wrong answer");
    break;
  case "D":
    System.out.println("Correct answer");
    points++;
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Please enter A, B, C or D");
}
```

Keep in mind, this is just demonstrating the programming logic. How you choose to display your results is up to you.